# PHPEXCel Read only one sheet to Array

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to only read values from  excel sheets 
if i use this code , it works fine without no problem:

```
  function ReadUploadedFile($Uploadedfile,$fileExtension)
    {
            class MyReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter
            {
                public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '')
                 {
                    // Read rows 1 to 7 and columns A to E only
                    if ($row>=1 && $row<=100) {
                        if (in_array($column,range('A','Z'))) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
}

        $filterSubset = new MyReadFilter();
        $inputFileType="";

        $inputFileType = 'Excel5';
        $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
        $objReader->setReadFilter($filterSubset);
        $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
        $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('myExcelsheet.xls');
        $sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
```

> $sheetData now is an array and i can use it with no problem.

what if i have many worksheets ,and i need to specify only one , as per documentation from PHPEXCEL , they say to use `setLoadSheetsOnly()`

i try the code blow but it doesn't work.

```
$inputFileType = 'Excel2007';   
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objReader->setReadFilter($filterSubset);
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly("Summary"); //my worksheet name is Summary
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load('myExcelsheet.xlsx');
```

so what should i write after the above line to convert this object to Array 
i try this

```
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
```

but it gives this error

> Call to a member function cellExists() on a non-object

and when i try this

```
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->toArray(null,true,true,true);
```

> Call to undefined method PHPExcel::toArray()

Comment: Why are you using the `Excel2007` Reader to load an `.xls` file? `Excel2007` is for OfficeOpenXML-format files. A `.xls` file should be a BIFF-format file. Either let PHPExcel pick the correct readers itself, or make sure you select the right reader for the file

Comment: sorry @markBaker , i edit it

Comment: I would guess that there is something, perhaps a formula, in your Summary worksheet that references cells in other worksheets that you haven't loaded... if that is the case, then telling `toArray()` to calculate formulae (the second argument) will trigger an error, because the formula cannot be evaluated

Comment: Is there any way to know the cell which cause the problem , 
my sheet is big

Comment: You'd need to loop through every cell checking for a formula, and testing whether there were any worksheet references in that cell.... PHPExcel doesn't provide any built-in function for that purpose

Comment: Can't you read in all worksheets, and just do the `toArray()` on the Summary worksheet?

Comment: problem solved , i change readfilters values for rows and columns  to get only cells that i need , worked with no problem , thanks.

Answer (score 3):

/** Here is my code work: */

```
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
define('EOL', (PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br/>');

/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$inputFileType = 'Excel2007';
$inputFileName = 'file.xlsx';
$sheetname = 'mysheey'; // I DON'T WANT TO USE SHEET NAME HERE

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly($sheetname);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);
echo ' Highest Column ' . $getHighestColumn = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex()->getHighestColumn(); // Get Highest Column
echo ' Get Highest Row ' . $getHighestRow = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex()->getHighestRow(); // Get Highest Row

echo "<pre>";
print_r($sheetData);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Work for me.

I'm using: **rangeToArray();**

"phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.3"

```
$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xlsx();
$spreadsheet = $reader->load('report.xlsx');
$worksheet = $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
$highestCol = $worksheet->getHighestColumn();

print_r($worksheet->rangeToArray("A4:$highestCol$highestRow", null, true, false, false));

// If you want to format data e.g. 2450 to 2,450
// You could set rangeToArray parameter at 4 = true
```

[image]